# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, android-databinding, java

Attempt to invoke virtual method:
 `void android.widget.Button.setTag(java.lang.Object)`
on a null object reference.

error when I use `androiddataBinding` on Button like:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@{userInfo.isEmpty?@drawable/shape_gray_corner:@color/colorWhite}"
    android:text="@string/text_login"
    android:onClick="onViewClik"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_24" />
```

Comment: Did you use the binding tag and binded the button correctly to your activity?

Comment: yes，android:background="@drawable/shape_gray_corner" is ok,just get error when use android:background="@{userInfo.isEmpty?@drawable/shape_gray_corner:@color/colorWhite}"

Comment: Can you check this programmatically inside your model and userInfo.getImage here in drawable. And also what are you checking a Object null or not? Check userInfo.name something like that

Comment: I would try to use an expression change button background

Comment: One is drawable other is color write. Its the problem i think.

android:background="@{userInfo.isEmpty ? @color/colorWhite : @color/your_default_color}"
Please try this

Comment: show your userinfo class

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try default color instead of drawable
or use drawable at both places.

like this

```
android:background="@{userInfo.isEmpty ? @color/colorYellow : @color/colorWhite}"
```

Comment: thanks,i Tried，but not work 
I solved by another method android:background="@drawable/selector_button_enable"
            android:enabled="@{!TextUtils.isEmpty(userInfo.login_name)&amp;&amp;!TextUtils.isEmpty(userInfo.password)}"